# B-spline derivative

Tags: probability

I used this control point vector: {{$0, 0$}, {$\pi/2$, $1.7$}, {$\pi$, $0$}, {($3\pi/2$, $-1.7$}, {$2\pi$, $0$}}, and this knots vector (by chord length method):{$0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1, 1$}. My scope was to approximate $sin(x)$ function. OK!

When I tried to do the derivative of the above approximated function I got strange results! New knots vector:{$0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1$}, and new control point vector:{{$6.28319, 6.8$}, {$6.28319, -6.8$}, {$6.28319, -6.8$}} gave not an approximation of $cos(x)$ function, as I hoped. Why? What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems:

First, there's something wrong with the values you interpolated. How can the sine of $\pi/2$ be 1.7?? In fact, how can the sine of anything be 1.7?

Next, your b-spline is rather unusual. You have $n=5$ control points. So, to construct a spline of order $k$, you will need $n+k$ knots. In your case, you have 10 knots, so $n+k=10$, so $k=5$. In other words, your spline must have order 5, so degree 4. But, for a spline with degree 4, you would normally use a knot sequence that begins with 5 zeros and ends with 5 ones. So, your knots are puzzling.

Finally, since you are using chordal knot distances, you appear to be creating a parametric (2D) spline. The first derivative of this spline will be a 2D vector. This vector will be somewhat related to the cosine function, but the relationship will not be as simple as you are expecting.